# Convert a polynomial to Hypergeometric equation

Tags: polynomials, hypergeometric-function

How can I convert this polynomial to Hypergeometric equation.

$$Pn=n!\sum_{r=0}^{\frac{n}{2} } (-1)^r\frac{(p-1)!}{(p-n+r-1)!} \frac{1}{r! (n-2r)!}2x^{n-2r}$$

Comment: Where did this polynomial come from?

Answer (score 3):

I think that you need to consider two different cases and almost then use the definition of the gaussian hypergeometric function to get
$$P_{2n}=\frac{2 (p-1)! }{(p-2 n-1)!}\,x^{2 n} \, _2F_1\left(-n+\frac{1}{2},-n;p-2
   n;-\frac{4}{x^2}\right)$$
$$P_{2n+1}=\frac{2 (p-1)! }{(p-2 n-2)!}\,x^{2 n+1} \, _2F_1\left(-n-\frac{1}{2},-n;p-2
   n-1;-\frac{4}{x^2}\right)$$